# How to set intro page before homepage in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to set introduction page before home page load.

In short when user hit / enter domain name, first of all it should be show an introduction page and once click on `Enter Site` button user can redirect to the homepage.

Is it possible to implement this kind of functionality?

Comment: Please see below url for your query- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11453424/add-landing-page-before-homepage-magento

Answer (score 0):

You can create one custom module and override the `initControllerRouters` in your **Model/Observer**.

Create one CMS page or PHTML file and then you can set the block for the same.

```
class Companyname_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId();
    public function initControllerRouters ( $request ) {
         $html = Mage::getSingleton( 'core/layout' )->createBlock( 'core/template' )->setTemplate( 'custom/custom.phtml' )->toHtml();
    }

}
```

You can also take and maintenance extension and customize it which would help you for the same.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you can create introduction page and set it as homepage

click on enter site redirect to current homepage cms page